# Globalization + Ghana Africa

Tags: localization, internationalization, globalization

Just curious, but has anyone done globalization in an application for Ghana, Africa? I've been searching all over the Internets to no avail. Is the predominant language tag *en-GH*? I am currently developing an application for deployment in a Ghanaian medical facility and have been worried about localization issues. *Any pointers? Resources? Anything?*

Thanks!

Comment: I think many things are going to be identical to British English. That's mostly what they use as the official language.

Comment: You are exactly right. Since having posted this question I have traveled to Ghana and found that many things are identical to the British culture/locale. The main difference is of course their currency, the cedi. I'll post an answer to my own question in case someone else is looking. Thanks Attilah!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CIA World Factbook for Ghana](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/gh.html), the language breakdown is Asante 14.8%, Ewe 12.7%, Fante 9.9%, Boron (Brong) 4.6%, Dagomba 4.3%, Dangme 4.3%, Dagarte (Dagaba) 3.7%, Akyem 3.4%, Ga 3.4%, Akuapem 2.9%, other 36.1%. English is the official language, though.

If you're developing an application for a Ghanaian medical facility, why don't you ask someone at that facility who will be using your application?

Comment: That would be great, but communication is extremely scarce (not due to a lack of trying). The language of the application will be English only, but I'm concerned about numbering, currency formats, and dates. The research that I have done thus far has led me to believe that many things are identical to the en-GB locale in formatting of numbers and dates.